# Check if my app is installed on a Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a few Windows Phone apps in the store and each of my apps has a "More apps" part where I promote all of them. Is it possible to know if they installed one of my apps so I don't show it in the list anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher`: Returns all the app packages with the same publisher ID as the app calling this method, details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher(v=vs.105).aspx